# release int in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

do you need to release int in objective-c? How can we tell if something needs to be released or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read this : http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

You don't need to release an integer if you didn't do a dynamic allocation.

It's more A C question..

Answer (score 2):

double, float, int and  char do not need to be release cause they are not allocated dynamically, except if you do something like this :

```
int *toto = new int(1);
```

You will need to release your integer ;-) .
However all object need to be released (NSString, NSArray etc... have to be released).

Hope it will help you.